# auto generation of serial version uid using maven2 plugin

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-plugin, serialversionuid

Is there a maven plugin which automatically calculates and updates serial version uid for all java class files implementing the Serializable interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any Maven plugin that can add this functionality, but you could call the [Serialver Ant task](http://serialver.sourceforge.net/) using the [Maven AntRun Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) in the `process-sources` phase of the lifecycle.

Comment: Did you mean `process-sources`?

Comment: I will probably go with antrun for the time being. thanks very much

Comment: There exists a maven plugin for that. Look at the answers below.

Answer (score 4):

A Maven module named maven-svuid-plugin is available to do what you want. Please look at https://bitbucket.org/lp/maven-svuid-plugin/wiki/Home

Comment: This plugin can only change value of the fields but not add them if they are missing.

Answer (score 2):

The [compile mojo](http://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html) of the [AspectJ compiler Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin) has a [XaddSerialVersionUI](http://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#XaddSerialVersionUID) parameter that:

> Causes the compiler to calculate and add the `SerialVersionUID` field to any type implementing `Serializable` that is affected by an aspect. The field is calculated based on the class before weaving has taken place.

So you could apply a fake or empty aspect and use this plugin to weave your classes (it's not ideal but I don't think that modifying Java sources directly is really a good practice neither).